# Capture tap when dismissing keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I cannot seem to figure out how to capture the tap that a user does when they tap outside of a keyboard. The main issue is I have a send button that **is not** part of the keyboard and I want if they tap it, while the keyboard is open for the send to occur. Currently the user taps the send button which dismisses the keyboard then if they tap the send button again it will send the text.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `tapGesture` to your `view`:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped(_:)))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Which will call `self.view.endEditing(true)` and dismiss the `keyboard`.

```
func viewTapped(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: I already have one and that does not get hit if they keyboard is being dismissed.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you want to dismiss the keyboard and send the text at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

This does not require any gesture recognizer, and will capture any contact with the screen, dismissing the keyboard.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    view.endEditing(true)
}
```